# MVC 5 c# reporting errors back to the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

we have an MVC application , what is the best way to record errors generated (by users) back to our support database? users should only see "this error has been reported" error message

all the details should be written to to a database

please help!

Comment: what happens if there is an error connecting to the support database? tbh the best place to log errors is to a text file on the application server.

Comment: Make use of logger...like log4net that will log to your database

Comment: @user1666620 Be careful claiming "best" practice. You'll find opinions differ (especially when the log files have filled up the filesystem).

Comment: i think this should be moved to programmers.stackexchange since this isn't about a specific error but is a design question

Comment: @richard if you're at a stage where the filesystem has been filled with error logs then i don't think storing them in a database will help matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you either make use of External library like Log4Net or create you own library class which will do logging for you.

One more suggestion is make use of `ExceptionFilter` which is avaiable in MVC file and write code of logging in that filter. I am suggesting becuase it will not cause you to write code again and again it follows DRY principle.

Example :

```
public class CustomExceptionFilter: FilterAttribute,  
IExceptionFilter   
{  
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)   
    {  
        if (!filterContext.ExceptionHandled)   
        {  
            //log error here 
            Logger.LogException(filterContext.Exception);
            //this will redirect to error page and show use logging is done 
            filterContext.Result = new   
                        RedirectResult("customErrorPage.html");  
             filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;  
        }  
    }  
}
```

than you can do like this

```
//Over controller  
[CustomExceptionFilter]  
public class HomeController:Controller 
{  
   //......  
}  


//Over the Action  
[CustomExceptionFilter]  
public ActionResult Index() 
{  
   //.......  
}
```

Check this for log4net : [log4net Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial)